# moving cakephp 3 to production, gives missing element error

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have uploaded my cakephp 3 app to production, I can login, but then getting the following error:

```
Element file "Element/sidebar/left_menu.ctp" is missing.
```

The weird part is, that on my local dev, it works.
The file is there.

Is there anything I am missing?

Cheers,

Comment: Is the element for sure there? Is the case correct, or should it be `Element/Sidebar/left_menu.ctp` by any chance?

Comment: Yes that worked, but is weird as on my local it works fine with the small s.

Comment: I'm going to assume that your local machine is Windows, where the file system is case insensitive.

Comment: Nope it is mac. So could be the same